# Finding a basis for a field extension $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}).$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I am looking to find a basis for the field extension $$\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}).$$

Clearly as far as I can tell the elements $i$ and $\sqrt[4]{2}$ would be in the basis, as neither of these elements is in the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. However, when it comes to finding other elements in the basis, all that I could really think of at first was $i\sqrt[4]{2}$. Then I supposed that we would also need $\sqrt[4]{2}^3$ and $i\sqrt[4]{2}^3$ in the basis too, and later wondered whether $i \sqrt{2}$ would also be required. I think not because it would be covered under the element $i$ as $\sqrt{2}$ is contained in the field but I am not certain.

As it took me a while to find each of these 5 elements, I am wondering whether this is actually all the elements that would be required to form a basis, whether I am missing any elements or have too many. Any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: What's the degree of the extension?

Comment: I think it should be degree 4 by the Tower Law, and now upon further examination would that mean that as $i\sqrt[4]{2}^3 = i\sqrt[4]{2} \cdot \sqrt{2}$ that this term is unnecessary?

Comment: But then the same could be said for $\sqrt[4]{2}^3$ so I am unsure

Answer (score 2):

Note that $i\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, so $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2})$ has degree $8$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Hence it has degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

A basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is $\{1,\sqrt[4]{2})$.

Can you finish? You still have to add $i$.

Comment: after thinking about the problem would $1,i, \sqrt[4]{2}, i \sqrt[4]{2}$ be a suitable basis?

Comment: @UsernameInvalid Yes, correct.

Answer (score -1):

I think (2^¼)^2=√2 this imply that √2∈Q(2^¼) that is Q(√2) Contained in Q(2^¼) therefore degree of i over Q(√2) is 2 that is  degree of Q(2^¼, i) over Q(√2) is 2 therefore basis of Q(2^¼, i) over Q(√2) contains only two element namely {1,i}.